# Etymology of 'commode' into French and then English

Tags: etymology

> [[ Etymonline for 'commode (n.)' ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pare&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   1786, "chest of drawers," earlier (1680s) name of a type of fashionable ladies' headdress, from French *commode*, noun use of adjective meaning **"convenient, suitable,"**
>   from Latin *commodus* "proper, fit, appropriate, convenient, satisfactory,"
>   from ***com-*, intensive prefix** (see [com-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=com-&allowed_in_frame=0)), + ***modus* "measure, manner"** (see [mode](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mode&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)). Meaning "chair housing a chamber pot" first attested 1851 from `notion of "convenience."` ...

I heed the Etymological Fallacy. [But what are some right ways of interpreting this etymology, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

1. How did ***com-*** and ***modus*** combine to mean the French 'commode' ?

2. Then how did the French 'commode' narrow into the English 'commode', which inherited fewer meanings?

3. My problem: Etymonline above states that 'commode' undertook `the notion of "convenience"` only in 1851. So this later acceptation does NOT explain or answer how already in the 1680s, 'commode' already meant 'a type of fashionable ladies' headdress'.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Latin, commodus,-a already had the same adjectival meaning.
2. In French, commode originally only meant 'easy, convenient'. Later on, the adjective was substantivated to represent the piece of furniture -- which was easy to use. See the CNRS' website [1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/commode).